# Compare Rows with Header then insert value in column with duplicate check in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, compare

Hi Everyone I'm new to VBA Code & I'm Stuck with this one. I hope someone help me..

Step 1:  compare the row with every SU headers.  Here in row2, the value in SU_BS is 211. Once there is a value in SU , the column NAME2 should display the corresponding NAME (s1) with SU value (211). So NAME2 should display s1 211.

Step 2:  Once NAME2 display the value, want to move to the next row without further checking SU headers.

Step 3:  As per step 1 & 2 the column NAME2 in Next row will also display S1 211. But what i need is while filling the value, NAME2 column should check for the duplicate value. If duplicate value exist the control moves to next SU header. If the SU header has no value, move on to the next SU header if value exist NAME2 should display the value (S1 ZY) in row3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to store each row and previous row in turn, compare elements until different.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim k As Integer, kLast As Integer
    Dim ar(4, 1) As String
    
    r = 2 ' start row
    While Len(ws.Cells(r, 1)) > 0
    
        ' fill array
        For n = 0 To 3
           c = n * 2 + 4
           ar(n, 1) = ws.Cells(r, c)
        Next
        
        k = 0
        If r > 2 Then
           ' compare
           While k <= kLast And ar(k, 1) = ar(k, 0)
              k = k + 1
           Wend
           ' skip pass any blanks
           While Len(ar(k, 1)) = 0 And k <= 3
              k = k + 1
           Wend
        End If
        
        ' output
        ws.Cells(r, 3) = ws.Cells(r, 2) & " " & ar(k, 1)
        
        ' remember last row
        For n = 0 To 3
           ar(n, 0) = ar(n, 1)
        Next
        kLast = k
        r = r + 1
        
    Wend
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```